# Why slideUp effect doesn't work on a div that has table-row display

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideup

I'm using div for generating table display :

```
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            Id
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            Name
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            Age
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            Joe
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            25
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            Robbin
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            33
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row" id="row">
        <div class="table-cell">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            Mark
        </div>
        <div class="table-cell">
            62
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to my table-row has slideUp effect but it doesn't work.
this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EfSm6/) describes my problem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/EfSm6/6/)**

Animations are not supported for table rows, You can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` but not animations like `slideUp()`, `slideDown()`

Try this

I have changed your css

```
.table-wrapper{
    display:table;
}
.table-row{
    width:200px;
}
.table-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:5px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/EfSm6/7/)** of `fadeout()` without changing your table format

Hope this helps,Thank you

Comment: but your solution hasn't tabular format.you removing table-row display.and each column has equal width.

Comment: Because animations are not supported on  table rows.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, its working ;-D

```js
$('.tr').click(function() { 
  $($(this).find('.td')).animate({padding: '0px',height: '0px',fontSize: '0px'},200);
 });
```

```css
div { box-sizing: border-box; }

.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.thead { 
 display: table-caption;
 padding: 5px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

.tr {
    display: table-row;
 box-shadow:  inset 0px -1px 0px black; /* This simulate a Bottom-Border */
 width: 100%;
}

.tr:nth-child(2n) { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); }

.td {
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 padding: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
    <div class="thead">This DIV colspan="3"</div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td" style="width: 10%;">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td" style="width: 10%;">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Click every row</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>  
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>   
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>
        <div class="td">Blah blah</div>  
    </div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/InsaYn/90cy8kqt/)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what you had to change and why

Comment: i had forget the box-sizing: border-box; ;-D
the box-shadow on .tr simulate the border-bottom. with border-bottom, 1px stay after animate()